# php info not effect when edit value in php.ini on nginx webserver

Tags: php, nginx

I've already installed php, fcgi, nginx, the system running as no problem, but the problem happen when:

1. I update memory_limit in php.ini, then restart php-cgi, nginx, but when use phpinfo, theo memory_limit is not effected.
2. I install 2 new extensions: curl and memcache, add 2 lines: extension=curl.so and extension=memcache.so, restart php-cgi and nginx, phpinfo also not show up the value curl and memcache in phpinfo.

So, how should i do?Please help me.

Comment: Where does phpinfo() say php.ini is located? It should say next to 'Loaded Configuration File'.

Comment: Value in php info:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path  /usr/program/php//lib
Loaded Configuration File  (none)

Answer (score 1):

I found the error:

When run php-cgi i forgot point the php.ini path. So i update as:

```
/usr/program/php/bin/php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -n -c /usr/program/php/lib/php.ini
```

The system now ok. Thanks all.